# How to round it off string number after two decimal points which contains special characters?

Tags: java

I have got two strings change_inpoints and change_inpercentage .

I need to round it off after  two decimal points .

```
String change_inpoints = "510.663757";
String change_inpercentage =  "+0.095152%";
```

This is what i tried

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class RounditOff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String change_inpoints = "510.663757";
        String change_inpercentage =  "+0.095152%";
        double d_inpoints = Double.parseDouble(change_inpoints);
        DecimalFormat decimal = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        System.out.println("change in points " +decimal.format(d_inpoints));
        change_inpercentage = change_inpercentage.replace("+", "");
        change_inpercentage = change_inpercentage.replace("-", "");
        change_inpercentage = change_inpercentage.replace("%", "");
        double d2_percentchange = Double.parseDouble(change_inpercentage);
        DecimalFormat decimal_2 = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        System.out.println("change in percent " +decimal_2.format(d2_percentchange));
    }
}
```

But the issue with chnage_inpercent is that i am

1. loosing number before the decimal point
2. how can i add percentage symbol at the end ??

For example the current output for change_in percent is **.10**

it should be 0.10%

Could you please tell me how to do it in better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
new DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

instead of

```
new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

as # means "Digit, zero shows as absent "
For the percentage sign you could use the % prefix/suffix (0.00%).

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) you can find more information on DecimalFormat.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the format to

```
DecimalFormat decimal_2 = new DecimalFormat("0.00%");
```

This will put a zero before the dot and append the `%` char afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##%");
decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

the default rounding mode is "HALF_EVEN".

```
decimalFormat.format(change_inpercentage);
```